# Cannot override bootstrap style in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some difficulty trying to style some of my controls in my application.  I do not want the input to stretch accross the entire width of the screen, so I am trying to set the width.  Below is my form.

I have a form like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="form-control input-width" placeholder="email" type="email" />
        </div> 
    }
```

Here is my style "input-width":

```
.input-width{
    width:300px !important;
}
```

And my BundleConfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", 
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(

                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/Model Scripts/Main/Main.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/Site.css"));

            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        }
```

And here is my master layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
<body>

    @{Html.RenderPartial("_NavBar");}

    <div class="container" id="MainBody">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)

</body>
</html>
```

Why is none of my styles added to my controls? Is my order in which I load my style sheets wrong?

Comment: What is order of adding the stylesheets? Bootstrap should be added first and then your custom css file.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include the master layout page, where I load the styles and scripts

Comment: Assuming that `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` there is your custom style. Just try to put it below `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` and check again.

Comment: Any demo you can show to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why, but changing the order of "@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")" and "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")" seems to have solved my issue.  My Master Layout file looks like this now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

    @{Html.RenderPartial("_NavBar");}

    <div class="container" id="MainBody">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand styles which are expected to override default bootstrap values are located in 'Site.css'. Try to add it without bundle usage, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css">
</head>
<body>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_NavBar");}
    <div class="container" id="MainBody">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose that ASP Bundle engine renders your css earlier that bootstrap's.

Comment: It does not make sense that this would happen.  I still tried this, but it did not work.

Comment: @akemp, the problem is in the CSS itself then, could you show us a screenshot of developer tools in 'styles' tab, when you are focused on your '.input-width' control?

Answer (score 0):

Il you add .form-control this add to the input display: table-cell forcing the width to 100%. 
If you don't want to delete this class, check the specicficity of your css rules, try this:

```
.form-group .form-control.input-width
```